# Is there a good page to link to which describes accept rate?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

Sometimes I find myself adding a little comment to questions suggesting people with a 0% (or thereabouts) accept rate should accept some answers because their low accept rate might put people off answering their question.

After writing this a few times I wondered if there's a page I could link to which clearly and politely describes Accept Rate and the etiquette of when to accept answers for new users.  I had a look on the FAQ; there's [an entry for Accepting Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq/7933#7933) but this doesn't cover Accept Rate.

Is the answer to expand this entry on the FAQ?  Or should there be a new entry added specifically about Accept Rate?  I'm happy to do either.

Having a canonical place to link to would save me time typing the same comment repeatedly and might stop some of the less friendly comments that people with low accept rates can receive.

Comment: The FAQ entry has been updated with the details from the blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the blog post, there is already an FAQ entry for Accepting Answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about). This replaces the one linked to in your question. It explains the how's and why's around the accepting of answers. I have also now updated it with the details from the blog with regard to the accept rate.

Comment: I've accepted this is I'd rather link people to the FAQ which can be updated rather a static blog post which won't change in future.

Answer (score 3):

How about this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)? It is the initial announcement for the feature.

Some excerpts (highlighting added):

> It is **considered good manners to
> accept answers on your questions**,
> eventually, but accepting answers is
> not required. I personally consider
> anything at 70% or over quite good,
> meaning you accept answers on 7 out of
> 10 questions that you ask.

On the workings:

> The following rules are used in the
> calculation:
>
> - Questions must not be community wiki.
> - Questions must not be closed.
> - Questions must be more than 3 days
>   old.
> - Questions must have at least 1
>   answer.
> - There must be at least four
>   eligible questions as determined by
>   the above rules, otherwise the
>   statistic will not appear.

And to its semantics

> - If the stat doesn’t appear at all, it’s a new user, or someone who rarely
>   asks questions.
> - If you see a low percentage, it’s a user who asks a lot of questions but
>   accepts almost no answers.
> - If you see a high percentage, it’s an engaged user, someone who
>   frequently goes back and interacts
>   with their questions after asking.
> - If you see a middle of the road percentage, it’s an experienced user
>   who understands what accepted answers
>   are for.

Comment: This doesn't really tell you why you should work on your accept rate, it only tells you how it works.

Comment: should still be at least mentioned on the faq page.